# How can i display post offsets in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm actually using this short snippet of code to display some content on my website.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3');
    foreach($myposts as $post) :?>
                    content
<? php endforeach; ?>
```

And I wanted to know if there was a way to incorporate the offset function of wp into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'offset'      => 0,
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    content
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just look at [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).